# List on new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having some troubles getting the `li` on a new line when it's short of space from **the previous** `li`.

Everything works on bigger screens, tablet and mobile. But not on medium size screens. This is because it should be responsive in different ways. It's runned with Bootstrap making everything responsive and easy to understand.

The problem is that `Loa / Breadth (mld) / Draught` is a long word, so it's not enough space and is continuing on the next line. This means the text `Length p.p / Depth (mld)` is continuing on the right side. This should continue on the next line instead.

It's hard to explain. I would appreciate if you could [visit the link](http://kunder.higraf.no/bergerederi/fleet/mv-selvaagsund/) and minimize the window to see.

I also provide a screenshot to see.

[image: Problems with li]

```
<?php $renderfield = types_render_field('loa-breadth-mld-draught', array('raw'=>'true'))?>
<?php if(!empty($renderfield)){?>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
   <li class="semibold">Loa / Breadth (mld) / Draught</li>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
   <ul><span class="light"><?php echo(types_render_field( "loa-breadth-mld-draught", array( 'raw' => true, 'separator'=>'</li><li>') )); ?></span></ul>
   </div>
<?php } ?> 

<?php $renderfield = types_render_field('lengt-p-p-depth-mld', array('raw'=>'true'))?>
<?php if(!empty($renderfield)){?>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
   <li class="semibold clearboth">Length p.p / Depth (mld)</li>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
   <ul><span class="light"><?php echo(types_render_field( "lengt-p-p-depth-mld", array( 'raw' => true, 'separator'=>'</li><li>') )); ?></span></ul>
   </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?
I also think you should check out `word-wrap` and `word-break` commands

Comment: It would also appear that your HTML is invalid. `li` must be children of a `ul/ol`...an **only** a `ul/ol`

Comment: Oh my god your html .... there is a lot to redo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you forgot to use `.clearfix` on the parent of `.col-*` in your case, `<ul class="clearfix">` is needed. second thing is that, all `.col-*` classes contain `float: left;` property. in that case, if there is 2 lines in one side and only 1 line in another, the next column tries to fit in the line so it comes upward.

in your case you can do like this for those `.col-*` classes which you need to fix:

```
[class^="icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: -3px;
}
```

this should work.

Comment: also @Paulie_D is right, you have used invalid HTML codes. `<li>` should be immediate child of `<ul>` or `<ol>` but in your case it's random http://prntscr.com/bg706u i recommend replacing all those `<ul>` and `<li>` with `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear css after eachrow so I would suggest adding `clear: both;` to `.col-sm-4 css` . It will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add following css to `.semibold` class to remove word wrap ex. below:

```
.semibold{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```